# Maths, functions in latex, really basic

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, amsthm

I am trying to code the following;

> f:X->Y
>       x|->f(x)

where `->` is `\longrightarrow` and `|->` is `\longmapsto`.
However, my problem is that I am unable to get the `x` directly underneath the `X`. I tried the following code:

```
\\* $f : X\longrightarrow Y$
\\* $\hphantom{<1>}   $x\longmapsto f(x)$\\
```

However this doesn't get it directly under the `X` as desired.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry it didn't appear properly in this post, I wanted the small x directly under the big X

Comment: Use the `align` environment from `amsmath` package.

Comment: Is this expression supposed to occur in a two-line displaymath context with both lines set in the same font size, or is supposed to occur in inline math and with `x\longmapsto f(x)` fairly small and set below `f:X\longrightarrow Y`? Please advise.

Answer (score 6):

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    f: & X\rightarrow Y ,\\
      & x\mapsto f(x).
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would personally prefer the alignment offered by a direct use of `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}l@{}}
    f: & X & \rightarrow & Y,   \\
       & x & \mapsto     & f(x).
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

The first argument of `array` (i.e. `@{}r@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}l@{}` in this case) is a specification for the alignment of the columns, as found in the `tabular` environment. The `@{...}` part specifies the space between the columns and I use it here (as suggested by @egreg in the comments) to make the spacing more uniform with the rest of the document.

[image: Result]

Comment: IMO this gives too much space, and the `X \to Y ` part end up looking inconsistent with other `X\to Y` in the normal text

Comment: `\begin{array}{@{}r@{\;}c@{\;}c@{\;}c@{}}`

Comment: @egreg Thanks that's exactly what I was going to propose in a moment! Spot on as always =)

Comment: Edited as suggested by @egreg